# Django ORM how to use case when and use other objects value with filter?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

so i have 2 models:

1. label, label models is used to define what is the label of a "type" code example coupon type code 2, has label expired.

```
class Labels(models.Model):
    label_id= models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    label_type = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=50)
    label_code= models.IntegerField()
    label_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

example data:

[image]

2. coupon model used for coupon data

```
class Coupons(models.Model):
    coupon_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, null=False, unique=True)
    coupon_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    coupon_desc= models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    valid_date = models.DateField(null=False)
    status = models.IntegerField(null=False)
```

example data:

[image]

so i want to use `Case` `When` from django to filter the data and get `status_name` example if the coupon date is more than today then it's "expired" else it try to match the `Coupons.status` with `Labels.label_code`, here is my current attempt

```
label_status = Labels.objects.filter(label_type='coupon_status').all()
data = Coupons.objects.
            annotate(
                coupon_status_name=Case(
                    When(status=0, valid_date__lte=date.today(), then=Value(label_status.filter(label_code="2").first().label_name)),
                    default=Value(label_status.filter(label_code=status).first().label_name),
                    output_field=CharField()
                )
            ).all()
```

i am able to filter the first line on the **When()** function but i am not able to filter the label objects in the **default** parameter of case function that reference the coupon dynamically, so how can i do this ? i tried using OuterRef() like

```
default=Value(label_status.filter(label_code=OuterRef(status)).first().label_name)
```

but it gives me this error:

> This queryset contains a reference to an outer query and may only be used in a subquery.

The expected output is there will be a new dynamic field called `coupon_status_name` with condition
If coupon `valid_date` less than today date the value is 'expired'
Else the value will try to match `label_code` from labels model  and `status` from coupon model.
Both condition get their value from the label model.

**So TLDR;** im trying to achive this Postgree SQL with django ORM:

```
SELECT CASE  WHEN coupons.status = '0' AND coupons.valid_date <= CURRENT_DATE THEN (SELECT label_name FROM labels WHERE labels.label_type= 'coupon_status' AND labels.label_code='2')    
ELSE (SELECT label_name FROM labels WHERE labels.label_type= 'coupon_status' AND labels.label_code=coupon.status)   
END coupon_status_name
```

I am actually able to accomplish this using extra like this:

```
data = Coupons.objects.extra(
    select={
        'coupon_status_name':
        """
            SELECT CASE  
                WHEN coupons.status = '0' AND coupons.valid_date <= CURRENT_DATE 
                    THEN (SELECT label_name FROM labels WHERE labels.label_type= 'coupon_status' AND labels.label_code='2')    
                ELSE (SELECT label_name FROM labels WHERE labels.label_type= 'coupon_status' AND labels.label_code=coupon.status)   
                END coupon_status_name 
        """,
    }
).all()
```

But i can't use django `.filter()` on extra fields and i read on the docs that django is starting to deprecate this `extra` method, so if anyone can help me convert this to `Case()` `When` from django, i would appreaciate it thanks.

Any help is appreaciated, and please don't ask me to change the database structure thank you.

Comment: Can you please add the `Vouchers` and `Labels` models to your question and some minimal examples of input data and desired result

Comment: @IainShelvington i update the post with more detailed information, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i found a solution for this using `subquery()` and `OuterRef()`

```
label_status = Labels.objects.filter(label_type='coupon_status').all()
data = Coupons.objects.
            annotate(
                coupon_status_name=Case(
                    When(status=0, valid_date__lte=date.today(), then=Subquery(label_status.filter(label_code="2").values('label_name'))),
                    default=Subquery(label_status.filter(label_code=OuterRef('status').values('label_name')),
                    output_field=CharField()
                )
            ).all()
```

Answer (score 1):

You try to use unrelated object in a query that ask for relation that's the reason why you received an error. It's seems a bit counter intuitive to me to use a Model like this whereas Django is used to query relational database.

It's seems that Label and Coupon interact to each other. As Label is a kind of Coupon status ?
you should try to add a Foreign Key between the two. It will be a way more easier.
Something like this :

```
class Coupons(models.Model):
coupon_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
coupon_desc= models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
valid_date = models.DateField(null=False)
status = models.IntegerField(null=False)
label_status = models.ForeignKey(Label)
```

Also you shouldn't overwrite primary_key, Django don't really like that, it can cause some errors.

Comment: A label purpose is to translate code like 1,2,3 to their respective name, example coupon_status, page_status, i actually able to acomplish what i want with select() extra from django queryset but the dynamically generated field is not filterable by django .filter(), so what i do is manually filter the field by python list but it is a lot slower

Comment: Well... if it's work but i still think you could improve your database by creating realtion between object or think what are attributes objects should have... Database is the cement of your project, don't hesitate to improve it